# Grunt: how to concat a .CSS file onto my compiled .SCSS files?

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, concatenation, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm learning grunt and it's wonderful!

**background:**

My project is built using SASS (`.scss`), and I use grunt's `compass` plugin to compile multiple `.scss` into a single `.CSS` on output.

**problem:**

I am using a jQuery plugin which has a `.css` file associated with it. I want my Grunt to do as follows:

1. Compile *.SCSS into `frontend.css`
2. when done, concat `plugin.css` onto the end of `frontend.css`
3. minify `frontend.css`.

I have tried adding a concat rule for my CSS, which runs after the grunt compass compiling. The concat rule is shown below.

```
concat: {
  css: {
    src: ['www/assets/css/frontend.css',
          'bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/css/plugin.css'],
    dest: 'www/assets/css/frontend.css'
  }    
}
```

Here is what the grunt task looks like:

```
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['newer:concat:vendors', 'copy', 'uglify', 'compass:dist', 'newer:concat:css', 'newer:cssmin', 'newer:imagemin']);
```

Here are a list of the Grunt plugins I am using:

```
 // Load Grunt Tasks 
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
```

if I call `concat:css`, plugin.css is concatenated, however each time I run the task it is added on again, again, and again, so multiple copies of the same CSS are being inserted into the file.

if I call `newer:concat:css`, the file is not ever concatenated onto `frontend.css`.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Why not just copy `plugin.css` into a new `plugin.scss` file? That is typically what I do.

Comment: @sdsanders He is installing the css with bower, so he probably can't rename it permanently.

Comment: @sdsanders, like  jgillich pointed out I'm using bower so I'd prefer not to do that. :) Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Prefix Another way to fix this with Grunt is outlined [here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/556#issuecomment-15718564).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use [grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean), which can simply delete the file on every build:

```
clean: {
    css: ['www/assets/css/frontend.css']
}
```

Or without installing a plugin:

```
grunt.registerTask('clean:css', function () {
    grunt.file.delete('www/assets/css/frontend.css');
});
```